# How to prove the problem about transformation of matrix

Tags: linear-transformations

> Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb F$, and suppose that $T\in\mathcal L(\mathcal V)$ is a linear operator having the following property: Given any two bases $b$ and $c$ for $V$, the matrix $M(T,b)$ for $T$ with respect to $b$ is the same as the matrix $M(T,c)$ for $T$ with respect to $c$. Prove that there exists a scalar $a\in\mathbb F$ wish that $T=aI_V$, where $I_V$ denotes the identity map on $V$.

Comment: Please write down the exercise. I know that you have posted the link. But what prevent you from writing down the exercise ?

Comment: I posted it as a link

Comment: Cuz I don't know how to write questions in mathematics ways. Maybe I have to learn how to print math symbols.

Comment: Here are some basic Information about MathJax. http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference But more important is that you post some of your thoughts. You can made an edit of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $n$ the dimension of the vector space and $\Lambda$ any change of basis matrix in this space ( from a basis $\{b\}$ to a basis $\{c\}$) . This means that $\Lambda$ can be any non singular matrix in $M_n(\mathbb{F})$. Now we have:
$$
M(T,b)=\Lambda^{-1}M(T,c)\Lambda \Rightarrow \Lambda M(T,b)=M(T,c) \Lambda 
$$

and , if $M(T,b)=M(T,c)=M$ this means $\Lambda M= M\Lambda$ , i.e. $M$ commute with all nonsingular matrices. This is possible only if M is a matrix in the center of $M_n(\mathbb{F})$, i.e. a matrix of the form $\alpha I$ for some $\alpha \in \mathbb{F}$ ( see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_ring#Properties)).

Comment: you answer is easy to understand, thank you!

Comment: You are welcome !  Don't forget to accept if you like :)